# Changes to variable handling in PHP

Tags: php

I am unable to understand variable Parsing.
I have gone through this link [uniform_variable_syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) but this link is so hard me for understand.

```
class Test{

    public $var=array('baz'=>'a');

    function a(){

        return 'amazing_class<br/>';
    }
}

 function a(){

    return 'amazing_out_of_class<br/>';
}


$obj=new Test();

$bar='var';
echo "1. ".$obj->$bar['baz']();  //Output amazing_out_of_class

$bar=array('baz'=>'a');
echo "2. ".$obj->{$bar['baz']}(); //Output amazing_class
```

Now lets look at first case : `$obj->$bar['baz']()`
`($obj->$bar)['baz']()`  >>>   **($obj->var['baz'])**() >>> `a()` >>> amazing_out_of_class

Now i also suppose it `$obj->{$bar['baz']}()` parsed same as above and expected `Notice error : undefined Property a`

`$obj->{$bar['baz']}()`  >>>   **($obj->a)**() >>> **($obj->a)** is `Notice error : undefined Property a`

`Notice error : undefined Property a`  is my assumption according to first case but its output `amazing_class`

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple

```
$bar='var';
echo "1. ".$obj->$bar['baz']();  //Output amazing_out_of_class
```

For example $obj->$bar'baz' evaluates as bellow

```
$obj->$bar['baz']() -> $obj->$var['baz']() -> {$obj->a} () -> a()
```

Second One also evaluates as a

```
$obj->{$bar['baz']}() -> $obj->{a}() ( $bar['baz'] as a)
```

Reference :http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php
           [php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Please add, if anything is missing

```
$bar=array('baz'=>'a');
echo "2. ".$obj->{$bar['baz']}();
```

Comment: then $obj->a() should output amazing_class because you are calling method a() of class.

Comment: i have added more details   now $obj->$var['baz'] - > a and it becomes a() please check

Comment: why $obj->{a}() is not also {$obj->a} ()

Comment: its because $obj->$bar['baz'] $ is there so it evaluates $obj->$bar['baz'] first

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to change from

```
$obj->$bar['baz']();
```

To

```
$obj->{$bar}['baz']();
```

Final code would be as

```
$bar='var';
echo "1. ".$obj->{$bar}['baz']();  //Output amazing_out_of_class

$bar=array('baz'=>'a');
echo "2. ".$obj->{$bar['baz']}(); //Output amazing_class
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/915826

Comment: I am asking the concept rather than alternate solution of problem

Comment: to get the concept you need to visit php [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) if you got any problem then you can ask here. But the code you shared is giving error show I gave you working solution.